# XPATH - grab value in div class based on the text in the previous div

Tags: html, xpath

```
<div class="optexrow oid0 row1" data-oid="0"><div class="key">Gross Vehicle Weight</div><div class="value">1487 kg </div><div class="cf"></div></div>
```

I am trying to return the text "1487 kg " by using xpath:

```
//div[contains(., 'Gross Vehicle Weight')]/following-sibling::div
```

This is not picking up the correct value for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
//div[@class='key'][contains(., 'Gross Vehicle Weight')]/following-sibling::div
```

Got it!